# How do I display emojis when sending an email using Python, mtplib, and Mimetext?

Tags: python, mime, smtplib

Here is a photo of my current situation:

[image]

Of course it seems as though emojis can be sent, though my Norwegian flag does not.

I used the flag unicode [from here](https://flagsweb.com/norway-flag-emoji-%F0%9F%87%B3%F0%9F%87%B4/).

Here's the Python Code

```
`message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = 'email@gmail.com'
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = '\U0001F1F3\U0001F1F4  Hva skjer i dag?' # Used to represent Norwegian Flag

message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))`
```

Any advice would be appreciated!
Takk! (thanks) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for those interested. Microsoft bans the usage of country flags. Works on my linux machine.